# Python packaging - that __init__.py

Tags: python, python-module

Say I have a directory structure like this:

```
mydir
    __init__.py
    innerdir
        __init__.py
        mymodule.py
```

And the content of `mymodule.py` is simply:

```
def hi():
    print 'hello, welcome'
```

while both of the `__init__.py`s are **empty**.

Now if I am outside the `mydir` directory, and I open a Python prompt and try to `import mydir` and then use `mydir.innerdir`, I get an error (an `NameError: 'innerdir' is not defined`).

Same if I move into `mydir` directory, prompt there and try to `import innerdir` and `innerdir.mymodule`.

I can successfully `import mydir.innerdir`, but then I can use it only as `mydir.innerdir`, not as just `innerdir`.

Comment: you should be able to `from mydir import innerdir` now you don't have to use the whole path

Comment: Have you read [Packages](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages) in the tutorial? It explains pretty much all of what I think you're asking.

Comment: @abarnert I actuallt read it but I wasn't understanding the whole concept, I was just lost

Comment: @whatyouhide: No problem. Packages are a bit complicated to get your head around (especially in 2.x, where you have no relative imports, so each module anywhere in the package basically has to understand the entire package hierarchy). Glad you understand better now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of the stuff you describe, I'm not even sure what you expected it to do. But from your last paragraph, it sounds like you're pretty close, so let's start there.

> I can successfully import mydir.innerdir, but then I can use it only as mydir.innerdir, not as just innerdir. Why do I have to specify the whole path?

That's how `import` works in Python, even if you ignore packages and just have a bunch of flat stuff, or even just the standard library. For example, if you `import os`, you can do `os.listdir('.')`, but you can't just do `listdir('.')`.

And the solution here is the same as it is there:

```
from mydir import innerdir
```

This isn't actually very useful, because `innerdir` is a package with nothing directly defined in it. What you probably *really* want to do is `from mydir.innerdir import mymodule`. But this is how to do what you asked.

---

If you want to know why `import mydir` followed by `mydir.innerdir` doesn't work, I can explain that.

From the [Packages](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages) section of the tutorial:

> … when using syntax like `import item.subitem.subsubitem`, each item except for the last must be a package; the last item can be a module or a package but can’t be a class or function or variable defined in the previous item.

So, what you're doing shouldn't do anything useful at all. But what does it actually do?

It imports the package as if it were a module. This means anything you define in the package itself—functions, classes, even modules—will be available as a member of `mydir`. But that doesn't automatically import any subpackages or submodules inside the package directory—remember, you're importing it *as a module*, not *as a package*.

---

If you're asking about what happens when you run from inside `mydir` (or add it to your PYTHONPATH)… well, in that case, `mydir` isn't a package at all, it's just a directory full of modules and packages (in this case, just the one package, `innerdir`). It's pretty much like doing `from mydir import innerdir`.

Comment: Ok, that is fair. So this leads to what was the initial problem: see the edit to my post.

Comment: @whatyouhide: What exactly is the original problem? You mention a whole lot of different things. Are you asking why `import mydir; mydir.innerdir` is an `AttributeError`?

Answer (score 1):

A package directly-imported doesn't automatically place subpackages or submodules into its namespace:

```
>>> import mydir
>>> dir(mydir)
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__']
```

(Notice that there is no `innerdir` here.)

But if you import *through* a package, Python will connect the namespaces together:

```
>>> import mydir.innerdir
>>> dir(mydir)
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', 'innerdir']
>>> dir(mydir.innerdir)
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__']
```

(Notice that there is no `mymodule` in `mydir.innerdir`.)

Python allows you to say explicitly what some submodules to include automatically in a package using the `__all__` magic variable in the `__init__.py`, but by default it will just run the code in `__init__.py` code and not do anything else.

You can do any of the following:

```
import mydir.innerdir.mymodule; mydir.innerdir.mymodule.hi()
from mydir.innerdir import mymodule; mymodule.hi()
from mydir.innerdir.mymodule import hi; hi()
```

Alternatively, you can edit your `__init__.py` files to include `__all__` vars for wildcard importing.

```
# file mydir/innerdir/__init__.py
print 'Running mydir/innerdir/__init__.py'
__all__ = ['mymodule']
```

Then you can do stuff like this:

```
from mydir.innerdir import *; mymodule.hi()
```

Even crazier, you can eagerly import subpackages and modules (I don't recommend this!):

```
# file mydir/__init__.py
print 'Running mydir/__init__.py'
import innerdir

# file mydir/innerdir/__init__.py
print 'Running mydir/innerdir/__init__.py'
import mymodule
```

Now these will work:

```
import mydir; mydir.innerdir.mymodule.hi()
from mydir import innerdir; innerdir.mymodule.hi()
```

You might want to brush up on the [documentation for packages](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages), which explains all this and has a directory structure exactly like the one you show here.

Comment: Very interesting. The last option you mentioned is actually whatI expected. For the sake of curiosity, isn't the last option you mentioned what some built-in Python packages use? For example, when you `import os`, you can then use `os.path.isdir`, which makes me think of `path` as a module by its own. This means that `os` is both a module (`os.exit()`) **and** a package?

Comment: Packages do not usually make a point of eagerly loading subpackages and submodules. However, many packages have code in their `__init__` that requires some modules, so those modules will be in the package namespace as a side effect of the import.

Comment: BTW, the reason this isn't done is so using any one part of a package doesn't require parsing and loading into memory every single definition in every single subpackage and submodule. For large packages this makes a *huge* difference in memory usage and startup time! Avoid eager loading in `__init__` unless you have a very compelling reason!

Comment: @whatyouhide, `os` is an ordinary module, not a package. The `path` in it is from a `import (posixpath | ntpath | etc) as path` statement. `os.path` is just an alias to whichever `*path` module is native to the currently running platform. See [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html).